# Refresh/auto refresh Facebook comments box

Tags: facebook, comments, xfbml

I want to refresh the Facebook comments box per click and/or every 30sec.
I tried a bit with the FB.XFBML.parse function, but it doesn't work.
Has somebody a hint how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you clear the contents of `<fb:comments href="___" num_posts="2" width="470"></fb:comments>` before running FB.XFBML.parse?

Comment: Hi, we are also facing similar problem. We have the below code